# SQL server returns no record for any query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

1. Week ago, we logged an error that a query "Select columns From Table Where column = value" returns no records, but the data was there for sure.
2. Same error as above happened again 3 times today. But obviously that data is always there because that query success for most of time, and the data never been touched.

---

3. Same time today, we also found another error:  We use EntityFramework (6.1.40302.0) to do a count on a table, and we gets the error below:
   "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"

Apparently, after EntityFramework retrieve return result from a "Select Count(1) From Table Where column = value" query, it always expect to have one record, so it used .Single() internally.  But when this query executed, the Sql Server returns no record.
As for a "Select Count(1) From Table Where x = y" the server should always return a result, even when there's no matches (return 0)

The difficulty to track down this bug is, I can't reproduce it.  It only happens couple of times, which been logged.

We've also noticed, the bug happens, the SQL server is either busy or there's long running transaction.

We're using SQL Server 2016.

Anyone else experienced it ever?

Thanks.

------- Update

I've attached the query that managed to dig out from EF:
Apparently this query should always return something, 0 or some number, but not no records.  Even if there's other process locking resource / uncommit transaction etc.

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[FileRecords] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[FileStatusId] IN (1000, 2000, 5000)) AND ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0)
)  AS [GroupBy1]



-- p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

It is generated by an EF Linq query:

```
Context.FileRecords.Count(f => openStatus.Contains(f.FileStatusId) && f.UserId == userId)
```

Comment: There could be many reasons this is happening. The first thought that comes to mind is running queries with READ UNCOMMITTED or NOLOCK hints. But there just isn't much detail here to offer much more than conjecture.

Comment: Run SP_WHO2 in the SQL Server, look for the BlkBy - If there is a blocking it would point to SPID which is doing so. It would go like a list and find the end point. And try to kill that spid [KILL (SPID)]. You can use dbcc inputbuffer(spid) to check the last query sent. You can google and get more info on SP_WHO

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some scheduled job running and rebuilding the data in that table on a regular basis?  Maybe these times when it randomly returns no data, is because the job is in the middle of running and there IS no data at that moment, then by the time you double-check the job has finished and the rows are back in the table?  Would also explain why SQL Server is so busy when this happens, if the scheduled job is using a lot of resources.

Comment: @SeanLange  I understand you suggest it could because other user/process's transaction. But no matter what, a Select Count query should always return something, or throw exception.

Comment: @Shan I don't think it is caused by other something else blocking.  If the resource is blocked, it should timeout rather than return nothing.

Comment: @JoeIrby I'm sure the schedule job that doing maintenance job that rebuilds indexes wasn't running.

Comment: Maybe your code isn't executing? There are so many possibilities here because we have no details. Maybe you have a try/catch...maybe...who knows? We have seen no code at all, only a text explanation.

Comment: @SeanLange I've updated the question a bit with more detail.  The code is executing.  I have put a wrapper around EntityFramework's command, to trap the actual query that being executed.  And I managed to find this query.  The query returns no record when error happens, which is not expected at all.

Comment: Can you run a sql trace and capture the actual query that is being executed in sql server? That may shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: @SeanLange I would like to run a sql trace if possible, but I can't reproduce this error at all.   This error only happens couple of times this month. Same code been running for 3 years without issue until now (upgrade to SQL 2016)

Comment: I understand you can't capture it when the error happens but you can capture the actual query being executed.

Comment: @SeanLange I have the actual query being executed (updated in the OP), it is logged by C# code.  I can't trap it from Sql Server. Because I can't run the sql profiler on production server all the time.  As this error may only happens once per month, there's no way for me to keep the profiler always on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138854/discussion-between-steven-xi-and-sean-lange).